# Is it possible to use a xamarin form in place of a winform on a local display?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a number of console application that use winforms to gather simple input from the user (Do this and click "OK", Did this happen click "Yes" or "No" That kind of thing) There is a new requirement that we provide the option to gather the simple input from the user on a handheld device that runs Android.

I had hoped to convert our winforms to Xamarin forms that could be used either locally or be sent to the handheld device. This is not my area, really, so it may be that I am not looking at the problem in the right way.

The system running the console application is usually a laptop or maybe a desktop.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: You want to log the user event like click a button?

Comment: Yes and sometimes ask the user to enter a number

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use App Center Analytics [Events Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/event-metrics) to track user event.

Here is the document for [Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/analytics/xamarin#custom-events):

> You can track your own custom events with up to twenty properties to
> understand the interaction between your users and the app.

```
Analytics.TrackEvent("Video clicked", new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "Category", "Music" },
    { "FileName", "favorite.avi"}
});
```